# Super Search {super_search_total_results} wrong when using start_on paramater

Tags: solspace

Like it says in the title. When using the start_on param in the {exp:super_search:results} tag then {super_search_total_results} doesn't take into account the start_on parameter and counts entries that should be ignored.

Short of using a second search tag with no limit and stashing {absolute_count} is there a way to fix this so the correct total count is supplied?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `start_on` is a parameter to `{exp:super_search:results}`. I'm pretty sure that `{exp:super_search:results}` is always an absolute count of the search results, and thus its value exists immutably when the page loads. This is why it's available within or without the tag pair.

You might be able to achieve what you're looking to do—present the number of results **you're** returning, vs what the actual **search** is returning—by doing a calculation on the `super_search_total_results` variable. Thus, `super_search_total_results - offsetValue = returnedResults`.

There are many math/calculation plugins available, but I'm partial to [Math](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/math) and have also used [Will Hunting](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/will-hunting) with good success.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, start_on is definitely working to restrict the results.

Will look into your suggestions. Temporarily I've done two searches, one to restrict the results for output (via an embed) and the other to get the count and this seems to be working - popped an `{if '{count}' == '{absolute_results}'}` and then output the count.